# QML accessing your qml component

Tags: qt, qml

I am using QML for developing a front end and I have an issue accessing a component from my main QML Window. So, my main QML window is something as:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: rootWindow
    objectName: "window"

    property Component mainScreen: MainScreen {} // my component

    // This is a slot that gets called from C++ side.
    // The function gets called fine.
    function videoDone() {
        mainScreen.doVideo()
    }
}
```

The `MainScreen` component is written in `MainScreen.qml` file as:

```
ControlView {
    id: mainScreenView
    objectName: "MainScreenView"


    function doVideo() {
        console.log("Called")
    }
}
```

However, this does not work as expected and I get the error:

```
TypeError: Property 'doVideo' of object QQmlComponent is not a function
```

I think the issue is that the full definition of `MainScreen` is not being seen at the ApplicationWindow level. I tried to see if I can cast it but no success.

Also `mainScreen.objectName` returns a null string rather than `MainScreenView`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the right way to use the `MainScreen` component is doing something like this:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: rootWindow
    objectName: "window"
    visible: true

    MainScreen { id: mainScreen } // my component

    Component.onCompleted: {
        mainScreen.doVideo()
    }
}
```

**MainScreen.qml** (same code than you, but I've used `Item` instead of `ControlView` just to check the compilation)

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Item {
    id: mainScreenView
    objectName: "MainScreenView"

    function doVideo() {
        console.log("Called")
    }
}
```

Another option would be to create the component [dynamically](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createComponent-method).

Comment: That was it! Thanks!

Comment: @Luca Great! :D Thanks to you. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

> Property Component mainscreen: MainScreen { }

Use

> Property var mainscreen: MainScreen { }

Here is sample code

**main.qml**

```js
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5

ApplicationWindow {
    id: rootWindow
    objectName: "window"
    visible: true

    property var mainScreen: MainScreen {  }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        mainScreen.doVideo()
    }
}
```

**MainScreen.qml**

```js
import QtQuick 2.6

Item {
    id: mainScreenView
    objectName: "MainScreenView"

    function doVideo() {
        console.log("Called")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just want something like this:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    // if you really need a property of your Item uncomment the following line:
    // property alias mainScreen : mainScreen

    MainScreen {
        id: mainScreen
    }
    function videoDone() {
        mainScreen.doSomething()
    }
}
```

and in the MainScreen.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Item {
    function doSomething()
    {
        console.debug("Test")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign id to your component.

ApplicationWindow {

```
id: rootWindow
objectName: "window"

property Component mainScreen: MainScreen {
    id: myMainScreenCmp
 } // my component

function videoDone() {
    myMainScreenCmp.doVideo()
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You have to import your component and your component name and filename must be the same.

MainScreen.qml

```
MainScreen {
    id: mainScreenView
    objectName: "MainScreenView"

    function doVideo() {
        console.log("Called")
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand. if I do this, I get the `MainScreen` is instantiated recursively error.